# Trouble with calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to call a function inside of a button click event.

```
$('#btn_save').button().click(function(){
   executeStatement(); 
});

$.fn.executeStatement = function(){
    alert("Here!!!");
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                          
      data: sqlStatement,                   

      dataType: 'json',               
      success: function(data)          
      {
        alert("Success!!!");
      } 
    });
  }
```

The problem is that it never gets called because it is undefined according to the debugger: `Uncaught ReferenceError: executeStatement is not defined`

Can someone give me a hint what is wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `$.executeStatement();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are trying to make a jQuery plugin (which I don't think you are?), change your function declaration to:

```
function executeStatement(){
   //code here
}
```

Comment: This one is working. I am just curious I tried to create another js file and declared this method inside. Then I tried to call it and it is not working again (undefined). (btw the new js file is imported..). How to do that so I can call it also from there??

Comment: @Husky I would need to see your HTML markup and the contents of both js files, otherwise its just guess work. Maybe post a new question as this isn't related to your function declaration question?

Answer (score 3):

Just to elaborate on the previous answer, $.fn is kind of like jquery's namespace. Anything that starts with $. is part of jquery. You can actually add functionality to jquery by adding functions to $.fn, but it's probably not what you want.

I found this really confusing at first too, so I thought I'd try to clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Curt's answer is completely correct. But I thought I would add to it.

```
function executeStatement(){}
```

this is called a function declaration and will work in this case.

```
var executeStatement = function(){};
```

this is called a function expression and will also work in this scenario.